# Microsoft visual studio error while debugging a project " load a program with an incorrect format"

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2015

My project was debugging correctly in the last time, but i open it now trying to debug, this exception is fired. 
[image: Exception]

my used assemblies are x64 bit so i set the project to x64 bit

**Note:**
1-This problem is happened when i made another new project but the new project is not depend on this project
2-The other projects are debugged correctly

i do not understand the main problem , is it in the Target platform, Active solution platform or what !

[image: Project properties]

[image: Build]

**update:**
when i close visual studio this new massage is displayed
[image: Message]

Any help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks i solved this problem and this is the answer

right click on project -> properties -> debug tab
in the section of Enable debuggers:   **check Enable native code debugging**.

[image: Solution]